# Is it correct to use colon in the following case?

Tags: punctuation

> One of my passions is to show Hawaii to the world: its beauty, history, mysteries.

Is colon the right punctuation here? If not, what's the correct one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's ok as it explains what it is about Hawaii that you feel so passionate about.

From [grammar monster](https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/colons_extend_a_sentence.htm):

> The Quick Answer
>
> A colon can be used to introduce some more
>   information about something mentioned earlier in the sentence. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> He wanted just one thing: revenge.
> He knew what his wish would be: the ability to turn stones into gold.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Colon, em-dash, or comma could all work there.  But you'd probably want to end the list with **and mysteries**.  It would be a stylistic choice.